# Allowing Comments on Posts

Tags: plugins, blog, blog-page

I'd like to allow users to write comments on my website's posts. I found this article (https://en.support.wordpress.com/enable-disable-comments-for-future-posts-pages/) so I went to Settings -> Discussion -> Default article settings -> enabled to allow people to post comments on new articles, but that didn't seem to do anything.

On my posts and pages, I don't have the option to check/uncheck “Allow Comments.” I'd be willing to write a plugin to enable this setting but I'm not sure where to start. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Mike

Comment: Hate to have to ask this, but have you enabled the Discussion checkbox via Screen Options up at the top?

Comment: And there's always the documentation: 
 https://codex.wordpress.org/Comments_in_WordPress.  Lots of good info in the WP Codex.

Comment: It's also possible that your theme doesn't support comments, which is more common if you're using a custom coded theme. It's worth trying a default theme (say Twenty Seventeen or similar) to see if that makes the comments section appear.

Comment: @CKMacLeod no problem! I actually didn't have it checked but even with the "Allow comments" checkbox checked I don't see a comments section below the blog posts.

Comment: @WebElaineI think you're right about the custom theme causing the problem. I'm a little worried about switching the theme on the site because I don't want to break anything, I haven't done any Wordpress theme development myself but I'll look at the theme code to see if I can figure it out. I don't think the configuration options via the dashboard will do anything at this point.

Comment: You should be able to "preview" a theme on your site before activating it (and making it visible to the public)